# Translating fields in node.tpl.php file with drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities, theming, i18n-l10n

I have a drupal English/French website. I have a custom content type called 'ad' with all sort of fields. I have created the file 'node--ad.tpl.php' in my theme directory to customize the display of the 'ad' content. I use pixture reloaded theme and DRUPAL 7.
In node--ad.tpl.php fields are displayed with this code:
  print render($content['field_my_field_name']);

I am trying to translate fields (both labels and values) by using 'field translation' module.

Field translation works when I CREATE or MODIFY a content via admin.

However, when I DISPLAY a content of type 'ad', fields are not translated. This is because drupal calls to 'node--ad.tpl.php' and the translation module is probably not invoked. When deleting 'node--ad.tpl.php', drupal calls the default node.tpl.php with a similar results.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advanced,

Notes :

1. I correctly activated every dependencies for the module.
2. User interface translation correctly works.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found out myself how to do this:

1. Translate field labels and values in "*Configuration > Regional and language > Translate > Import*". You should import the values as 'User Interface', not as 'Fields'. Do not specify a URL, only `msgstr` and `msgid`.
2. Now, you need to add your `t()` function in node.tpl.php for the translation to be effective, like so:

   - In the `node.tpl.php` file, to translate field label write something like this:
     `$content['field_my_field']['#title'] = t($content['field_my_field']['#title']);`
   - To translate field's value, use: `$content['field_my_field']["#items"][0]['value'] = t($content['field_my_field']["#items"][0]['value']);`

You can now render your field:

```
print render($content['field_my_field']);
```